# Plugins not found in sprinboot and maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, plugins

I have a new error in my project that is in the pom.xml file. How can I fix it?

The error below is
shown in IntelliJ idea:

```
Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found
Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:' not found
Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:' not found
```

Comment: You may want to start by giving steps to reproduce. Please check [ask] and edit your question with a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only add the version.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
</plugin>

<version>${project.parent.version}</version>


<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
```

Now its working.

Comment: Worked for me thanks, but to analyze what was the problem ? Why spring didn't take the parent version as usual ?